# Show the following: $a_{n-1} = a_{n} - ∇a_n $ and $ a_{n-2} = a_{n} - 2∇a_{n} + ∇^{2}a_{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show the following: 
$$a_{n-1} = a_{n} - ∇a_n $$ and $$ a_{n-2} = a_{n} - 2∇a_{n} + ∇^{2}a_{n}$$

-These two equations were presented to me in one single question and I am not sure where to go with this, is there a connection between the two that I am missing or a particular formula I should be using? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is $\nabla$? Perhaps the backward difference operator, i.e. $\nabla a_n = a_n - a_{n-1}$? In this case you would just plug in, being careful to realize that $\nabla^2 a_n = \nabla(\nabla a_n)$.

Comment: I am brand new to the ∇ operator, i know it's called the del operator from a quick search but we have not covered this in class, so i am completely lost in regards to its properties or how this problem would be played out.

Comment: Well, your first equation can only really make sense if $\nabla a_n = a_n - a_{n-1}$. That means $\nabla (\nabla a_n)=\nabla a_n - \nabla a_{n-1}=a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$. So that should be enough to do the second part.

Comment: @Ian I think I kind of see what you mean but I am having trouble actually applying it. Could you show me please?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that $\nabla$ is defined as the backwards difference operator: $\nabla a_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$. That makes your first problem a trivial algebraic manipulation. For the second, the natural first step is to investigate $\nabla^2a_n$:

$$\nabla^2a_n=\nabla(\nabla a_n)=\nabla a_n-\nabla a_{n-1}=a_n-a_{n-1}-(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})=a_n-2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}\;.$$

If that’s not clear, define a new sequence: let $b_n=\nabla a_n$ for each $n$. Then

$$\nabla^2a_n=\nabla(\nabla a_n)=\nabla b_n=b_n-b_{n-1}=\nabla a_n-\nabla a_{n-1}\;.$$

Now take a look at what you want to show: you want to show that

$$\nabla^2a_n=2\nabla a_n-a_n+a_{n-2}\;,$$

i.e., that

$$a_n-2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}=2\nabla a_n-a_n+a_{n-2}\;.$$

This is very straightforward at this point.